# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the service which imports JwtService

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am trying to use [@nestjs/jwt](https://github.com/nestjs/jwt). Particularly its `registerAsync` method (my config service loads the configuration asynchronously). I am registering `JwtModule` in the `AuthModule`, which then loads specific modules for each login/registration providers. Then I add `JwtService` to the providers of `EmailService` but it fails.

The structure of the application is as follows (very schematic):

**app.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    AuthModule,
    ...
  ]
})
export class ApplicationModule {}
```

**auth.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => ({
        secretOrPrivateKey: config.get('jwt.secret')
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService]
    }),
    EmailAuthModule
  ],
  exports: [JwtModule]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

**email.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [...],
  controllers: [...],
  providers: [EmailService, ...]
})
export class EmailAuthModule {}
```

**email.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class EmailService {
  constructor(
    private readonly jwtService: JwtService
  ) {}
}
```

Application fails with this error upon startup:

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the EmailService (UsersService, ?). Please make sure that the argument at index [1] is available in the current context. +70ms
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the EmailService (UsersService, ?). Please make sure that the argument at index [1] is available in the current context.
    at Injector.lookupComponentInExports (/Users/.../api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:146:19)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../api/node_modules/ts-node/src/_bin.ts:177:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nest js cannot resolve dependencies. in Auth service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51124374/nest-js-cannot-resolve-dependencies-in-auth-service)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Services are not global but can only be used in the modules that provide them themselves or import them from another module that exports the service.

The problem here is that the `EmailService` depends on the `JwtService` but the `EmailAuthModule` does neither provide the `JwtService` itself nor import a module that exports the `JwtService`. (Unfortunately, you left out the `EmailAuthModule`'s `imports` here.)

So to solve this you have to import either the `JwtModule` itself or another module that exports the `JwtModule` in the `EmailAuthModule`.